# Realm object is missing all properties except primaryKey

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a RealmObject model that my tableViewDataSource depends on. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath1` method is able to access the properties fine, but the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets all empty properties from the Realm object. I'm guessing this has to do with passing persisted Realm objects around but I'm not sure where to fix it.

```
//viewController...
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let books = realm.objects(Book)
    viewModel = BookListViewModel(books: Array(books), onSelection: onSelection, onDeleteFailure: onDeleteFailure)
}
//end viewController

extension BookListViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(BookTableViewCell.nibName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell
        cell.bind(bookCellViewModels[indexPath.row])

        // NOTE:
        // bookCellViewModels[indexPath.row].book all properties are valid strings
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bookCellViewModels.count
    }
}

extension BookListViewModel: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let book = bookCellViewModels[indexPath.row].book

        // NOTE:
        // all book properties are empty string or nil
        onSelection(book)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger is likely showing you all empty property values for the Realm object, because you're missing the [LLDB plugin](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/plugin/rlm_lldb.py).

### Install Realm Xcode plugin

#### via Alcatraz

The LLDB plugin comes bundled with the [Realm Xcode plugin](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#xcode-plugin), which is available on [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/).

1. Install Alcatraz, if not already installed.

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/deploy/Scripts/install.sh | sh
   ```
2. Open the Package Manager in Xcode (⇧⌘9 or Windows > Package Manager)
3. Search for *RealmPlugin*

[image: RealmPlugin in Package Manager]

4. Quit and relaunch Xcode to make sure the plugin is loaded

#### Compile yourself

You can also install the plugin manually by opening `plugin/RealmPlugin.xcodeproj` contained in the [release zip](https://static.realm.io/downloads/swift/realm-swift-0.96.2.zip) and clicking build.

### Install LLDB plugin only

Alternatively, you can install it as advised in the first code comments of the linked scripts or just execute the script below:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/Realm
wget -O ~/Library/Application\ Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realm/realm-cocoa/master/plugin/rlm_lldb.py
touch ~/.lldbinit
grep -q "rlm_lldb.py" ~/.lldbinit || echo "command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow-reload" >> .lldbinit
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it turned out to be a bug related to my view logic. I just was confused because the Xcode debugger shows all empty property values for the realm object, probably because they're all dynamic properties.