# Realm object property misses its value, but I can see it when printing the whole object

Tags: swift, realm

I stumbled upon a weird thing when trying to fetch an object from my Realm (iOS, Swift, Realm version 0.98.2)

```
print("speaker:")
print(RealmProvider.appRealm.objects(FavoriteSpeaker).first!)
```

Correctly dumps my object in the console:

```
speaker:
FavoriteSpeaker {
    name = Ashley Nelson-Hornstein;
}
```

But when I try to get the `name` property's value:

```
print("speaker name:")
print(RealmProvider.appRealm.objects(FavoriteSpeaker).first!.name)
```

I get an empty string

```
speaker name:
```

The four lines are together in my model's `init` method

---

**Update 1**: I found an answer that suggests that you merely don't see the values when printed in the Console: [Realm object is missing all properties except primaryKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806204/realm-object-is-missing-all-properties-except-primarykey?rq=1) but I also tried displaying the `name` property via an alert view and that is also empty.

---

**Update 2**: Just to make sure that everything happens sequentially and on the same thread I did this:

```
let favorite1 = FavoriteSpeaker()
favorite1.name = "Debbie Downer"

try! RealmProvider.appRealm.write {
    RealmProvider.appRealm.deleteAll()
    RealmProvider.appRealm.add(favorite1)
}

print("speaker:")
print(RealmProvider.appRealm.objects(FavoriteSpeaker.self).first!)

print("speaker name:")
print(RealmProvider.appRealm.objects(FavoriteSpeaker.self).first!.name)
```

But the result is the same - printing `name` prints an empty string

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `name` property is probably not declared as `dynamic`, which leads to it reading the `nil` value stored on the object itself rather than reading the data from the Realm.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue, thanks! This gets me thinking though - there must be a way for Realm to check this at startup, Swift does have some kind of inferior introspection skills ...

Comment: We've tried to find a way to check for non-dynamic properties, but it doesn't seem to be possible since it's not directly exposed and Mirror doesn't read things in the same way as actually using the property.

Comment: that's a pity because this issue will guaranteed keep re-appearing. all my objects had their properties dynamic but this particular object because I decided to add it last and in a hurry and missed to mark it as dynamic ... 

Comment: I would have never thought about this +1!